# How do I add custom component to the drawerNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to add custom component to my react navigation v4 :
this is my code:

```
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MapProfile: {
      screen: MapProfileTabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Maps",
      },
    },

    SportCentersList: SportCentersListNav,
    TermsAndConditions: TermsAndConditionsNavigator,
    About: AboutScreenNavigator,
  },
  {
    contentComponent: customDrawerComponent,
  }
);
```

I have a customDrawerComponent which I made as a component like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import SafeAreaView from "react-native-safe-area-view";
import { DrawerItems } from "react-navigation-drawer";

const customDrawerComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={styles.container}
        forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}
      >
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default customDrawerComponent;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

but I get a blank drawer, any ideas?

but the drawer stays the same, any ideas what I did wrong?